# Post-increment operator in function argument in Go, not possible?

Tags: go

How come, in Go (1.2.1), this works?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i = 0
    for i < 10 {
        fmt.Println(i)
        i++
    }
}
```

But this (with the increment operator in the function argument) doesn't?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i = 0
    for i < 10 {
        fmt.Println(i++)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Go, `i++` is a statement, not an expression. So you can't use its value in another expression such as a function call.

This eliminates the distinction between post-increment and pre-increment, which is a source of confusion and bugs.

Comment: *"Using variable names is the source of confusion and bugs, furthermore it can lead to compiler optimization errors. Thus, in go, we should use cpu register names."* :-) (Btw, your answer is useful)